# Install WIndows 10 on USB-C flash drive

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, windows

I have a macbook pro 2016 model. I want to install a windows copy via bootcamp. I dont want to install windows on my internal HDD so i was thinking about buying a USB type c flash drive and install windows there. Is this possible and would there by any issues like transfer speeds ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Boot Camp asks that you create a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows on your Mac.

Though I don't have experience with a USB-C MacBook Pro, USB is USB, differing only in speed and the type of connector. MacOS should not care what *kind* of USB key you have.

You will have to download the Windows 10 ISO to your MacBook Pro so Boot Camp can use it to create the bootable media but other than that it should work fine.